# How does bootstrap preprocess LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

In the `bootstrap.css`, I saw something like this:

```
@media screen, print {
  [class*="iconic-"] {
```

which looks like `LESS`. What I'm confused is that browser only know `css` instead of `LESS`. Is it converted to `css` by the javascript codes of bootstrap?

Comment: @limelights I googled it(`bootstrap`+`LESS`). I know LESS can be parsed and converted into by a server script. But as I understand, `bootstrap` is a client script. And I dont' know a client javascript script can convert `LESS` to `css` and then send to browser.

Comment: @Firegun: Less is usually used on the client.  http://lesscss.org/#usage  However, Bootstrap is not Javascript.  (although it does have an optional JS library)

Comment: Client side LESS should only be used for development.  When it is time for production, it should be compiled to a CSS file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> which looks like LESS

Wrong.

That's a [CSS media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 2):

This is not LESS, it's the [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) used to detects device dimensions or which method it should apply for (let say, for print method).